# VLC ActiveX Plugin freeze

Tags: c#, activex, vlc

I'd like to understand where my problem is coming from.. my app is always crashing after loading the **third** video into VLC. I get no error messages or anything it just freeze.

Heres my code to play a file:

```
private void launchVLC (string url, string title)
    {
        // Si le lecteur est déjà entrain de jouer on stop
        if (isPlaying)
        {
            vlcPlayer.playlist.stop();
            vlcPlayer.playlist.items.clear();
            isPlaying = false;
        }

        try
        {
            // Requête GET vers videos.php pour obtenir le lien direct vers la vidéo
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            // On récupère le lien
            HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            mediaUrl = myResp.ResponseUri.ToString();

            // On récupére le titre de la vidéo
            Uri uri = new Uri(mediaUrl);
            tabPlayer.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

            // Switch sur la tab ou ce trouve vlc
            tabBrowser.Hide();
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
            tabPlayer.Show();

            // Lancement de la vidéo
            vlcPlayer.playlist.add(mediaUrl, title, null);
            vlcPlayer.playlist.play();

            isPlaying = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Note: each time it's a different video, so it can't be a corrupted file or w/e could be happening because of the file.

Im using VS2017 and downloaded the latest VLC.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the crash streaming videos from a OpenWRT server and stopped trying after the 8th Video loaded fine. I didn't however let the videos play to the end before switching. Please could you provide more details as to how the videos are being streamed and what format they're being streamed in. if possible could you supply some sample urls to test your code with. There are a lot of potential issues outside of the code to eliminate in order to find the issue.

Comment: I am getting the videos from direct links, its usually mkv files encoded with x264 codec. Unfortunately thats all the details i can provide.. theres nothing special, i am just playing video via direct links, i tried switching videos before and after pausing but at the 3rd video it always freeze, memory usage is normal, cpu usage same.. can't really tell whats going on

Comment: Are you switching the control's visibility between videos? ActiveX is horrible for not being able to tell what's going on. perhaps look in event viewer to see if any error shows up there?

Comment: The only things i do is stop playing the video and then remove items from the playlist. I've been looking to the event viewer and theres nothing related with VS or my executable. Any ideas ? edit: so i removed the isPlaying condition and now im using next() instead of play(), it keeps crashing at the 3rd video but the sound from the second video is still playing in background and my form is still frozen.

Comment: As I mentioned ActiveX is painful to work with maybe try https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet which is a dot net wrapper around libvlc? It has a WinForms control available.

Comment: Yep i might try this way so i can switch to wpf instead.. but is there a way to get the vlc toolbar using this method ? I mean the default buttons, slider etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Then I checked the memory usage in taskbar, it was increasing. When the memory reached it's peek, the application doesn't give you an attention.
You need to run a thread to check the memory of the process that you are running. 
Run `GC.collect()` after disposing the player.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue,(i have just one el) but i solved it like this:

```
       this.axVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop();
        this.axVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear();

        this.axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(m_MRL, "live", ms_options);
        this.axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your answer, why it solves and what was the problem.